# Первый переход был невелик: от Кишинева до деревни Гаурени всего восемнадцать верст

Tags: синтаксис, пунктуация

Проверьте синтаксический разбор

(Пов, нев, сложн, бессоюзн, сост из 2-х частей)

1) (прост, двусост, не распр, не осл)
2) (прост, двусост, неполн, распр, не осл)

Comment: _1) …не распр._  (?) === 

Распространённое: имеется определение к подлежащему "переход" -- "первый". Остальное, по-моему, верно.

Comment: Предложения с нулевым именным сказуемом не являются неполными.

Comment: Серж, а почему именным  сказуемым? Обычное эллиптическое с пропуском простого глаг. сказ. со значением бытия : подлежащее  что? 18 вёрст, что о них говорится?- что они есть, находятся, имеются и т.д. где?-от Кишинёва...и т.д. А эллиптическое в школе называют неполным, всё верно, только "нераспространённое" слитно.

Comment: Людмила! А может быть, подлежащее -  восемнадцать вёрст, а сказуемое - от Кишинёва до деревни Гаурени? Смысл - то не в том, что они есть, а в том, что они от Кишинёва ...и далее по тексту.

Comment: @slava1947 Не могли бы Вы оформить ответ по всем правилам, а то вопрос "висит" как неотвеченный.

Comment: @Людмила Не могли бы Вы оформить ответ по всем правилам, а то вопрос "висит" как неотвеченный.

Answer (score 1):

В синтаксическом разборе также надо указывать двусоставное/односоставное и если предложение сложное, то сложносочиненное/сложноподчинённое.

Двусоставное - когда в основу входит и подлежащее и сказуемое.

С односоставным всё и так понятно.

Сложносочиненное - когда два простых предложения объединили в одно сложное. Пример: Я работал не жалея сил, а он все сидел, да отдыхал.

Сложноподчинённое - когда одна часть сложного предложения главная, а другая зависимая. Пример: Когда часы пробили десять часов, я поужинал и лёг спать. Я поужинал и лёг спать (когда?)-когда часы пробили десять часов.

Если ответ вам помог, отметьте галочкой (слева от ответа).